# Moving downloaded OneDrive file off Mac external drive

Tags: macos, mac, onedrive, external-drive

I've managed to download a 4.86gb file off OneDrive Cloud to a Mac. Now it won't allow me to move/copy it to an external drive. If I try any Mac file it doesn't like it either. But if I copy a file off external to Mac it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What is the external drive formatted as? If it's NTFS then you'd have to either reformat to HFS for Mac-only use or FAT for Mac/Windows.

An alternative would be to use something like Paragon NTFS for Mac - http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/ - which will then allow writing to NTFS drives.

Comment: Ok I'll try paragon. How do I find out what format my ext drive is ? Nfts?

Comment: In Disk Utility, if you select the Volume itself rather than the entire HD, then right at the bottom it will say Mount Point: then under that Format: ... which I'm guessing will say Windows NT Filesystem